# html overflow issue

Tags: html, css, scroll

I already asked this question, but I didn't explain it too well, so I removed the thread. Now I have made an example in jsfiddle to show my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/6APjt/

I want a page with a header and below that a canvas. This canvas expands when I click on the zoom button. When this canvas expands there is an overflow that I want to be visible with scrolling. This is because I want the header of the page visible all the time, also when I scroll to the bottom of the canvas.

In the example you see that i have used a div with style overflow set to hidden (to prevent that when you scroll, the whole pages is scrolled). I tried to solve this by adding another div in this div with the property overflow set to scroll. This solves the vertical scroll, but I can't scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your javascript!

```
testcanavs.height *= 1.25;
```

There is a spelling error in there, change it to this and it will work

```
testcanvas.height *= 1.25;
```

EDIT: Try setting height, or max-height on your containing div. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/6APjt/5/)

Comment: I don’t think that changes the scrolling issue though, does it?

Comment: sorry for the stupid mistake:) but indeed it doesn't solve the scrolling issue.

Comment: Good point, the scrollbar I saw was on the actual page, not the div. I will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your div will grow since height: auto is the default. Set it manually.

Comment: but I want that the div with class=show grows, so that the user can scroll the canvas without the header dissappearing. So it should grow horizontally and vertically, but it only grows horizontally for the moment